# Question on Spring Webflux Webclient reading a flux with delayed elements

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I newly started coding in Spring WebFlux and I am trying some of the behavior I observed.
I have 2 endpoints /customObjectsString and /customObjects

```
    @Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder
@ToString
public class CustomObject  {
    private final String text;
    private final Integer number;
}

  @GetMapping(value="/customObjects")
    public Flux<CustomObject> getCustomObjects() {

        CustomObject customObjectOne = CustomObject.builder().text("One").number(1).build();
        CustomObject customObjectTwo = CustomObject.builder().text("Two").number(2).build();

        return Flux.just(customObjectOne, customObjectTwo).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
    }

    @GetMapping(value="/customObjectsAsString")
    public Flux<String> getCustomObjectAsString() {

        CustomObject customObjectOne = CustomObject.builder().text("One").number(1).build();
        CustomObject customObjectTwo = CustomObject.builder().text("Two").number(2).build();

        return Flux.just(customObjectOne, customObjectTwo).map(customObject -> customObject.toString()).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
    }

 @Test
    public void testFluxAsString()
    {
        Flux<String> flux = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://localhost:8080").build().get()
                 .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/customObjectsAsString").build())
                 .retrieve().bodyToFlux(String.class);

        //This prints Received CustomObjectAsString at 2023.04.21.21.02.46CustomObject(text=One, number=1)CustomObject(text=Two, number=2)
        flux.doOnNext(customObjectAsString -> {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new java.util.Date());
            System.out.println("Received CustomObjectAsString at " + timeStamp + customObjectAsString);
        }).blockLast();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFluxCustomObject()
    {
        Flux<CustomObject> flux = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://localhost:8080").build().get()
                 .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/customObjects").build())
                 .retrieve().bodyToFlux(CustomObject.class);

        //this prints
        // Received CustomObject at 2023.04.21.21.03.26CustomObject(text=One, number=1)
        //Received CustomObject at 2023.04.21.21.03.26CustomObject(text=Two, number=2)
        flux.doOnNext(customObject -> {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new java.util.Date());
            System.out.println("Received CustomObject at " + timeStamp + customObject);
        }).blockLast();
    }
```

When I hit this url from chrome browser it displayed each string returned one after the other with 3 seconds delay in between
http://localhost:8080/customObjectsString

However When I hit this url from chrome browser it did not display the CustomObjet json one after the other. It waited for 6 seconds to receive all 2 CustomObjects and then displayed the entire thing as Json at once.
http://localhost:8080/customObjects

The tests which used WebClient also waited for 6 seconds and displayed both objects.
For /customObjects I see this
// Received CustomObject at 2023.04.21.21.03.26CustomObject(text=One, number=1)
//Received CustomObject at 2023.04.21.21.03.26CustomObject(text=Two, number=2)

For /customObjectsAsString I see this in long
//Received CustomObjectAsString at 2023.04.21.21.02.46CustomObject(text=One, number=1)CustomObject(text=Two, number=2)

1. I am trying to understand what is the difference between emitting string vs emitting a custom object as json.
2. Why did WebFlux's WebClient did not receive  one object at a time with 3 seconds gap between them? Is my webClinet code incorrect? should I write it in another way?
3. why did browser display each string with 3 seconds delay between them? Why did browser not display the customObject json in similar fashion?

I am trying to understand this behavior. Could experts please provide some insight into this.